# Get the type (Label, Button, etc.) of a kivy widget in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Is there any way to get the type of a kivy widget in python?

By type I refer to things like `Label`, `Button`, `TextInput` etc.

something like `my_widget.type` which e.g. allows me to put all `TextInputs` into one list.

Comment: Try `type(widget)`.

Comment: This only returns `<class 'kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy'>`

Comment: How are you getting the reference to the `Widget` that you pass to `type()`?

Comment: `for widget in widgets: print(type(widget))`

Comment: But using `print(type(self.ids.widget))` returns the same

Comment: Try `type(self.ids.widget.__self__)`.

Comment: That worked ,thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a normal reference to a `Widget`, you can use:

```
type(widget)
```

But if you have a `WeakProxy` (like the `ids` dictionary uses), then you need to do:

```
type(self.ids.widget.__self__)
```